# How to display two authors next to each other and one combined email adress centered below them?

Tags: author, email

For a practice assignment on Latex I need to reproduce a provided PDF with Latex.

Here is my problem:

The result I want, should look like something like this:

```
        The title of this document: XXXXXX
                Author1     Author2
            {au1, au2}@email-address.com
```

Two authors, one email address centered beneath them.

This is what I have tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\title{The title of this document: XXXXXX}
\author{Author1 \and Author2 \\ \texttt{\{au1, au2\}@email-adress.com}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle 
\end{document}
```

But with this the email address ends up centered under the right name and the author names are not properly centered under the title.

Since this is an introductory assignment, I likely do not need to use any fancy packages or a complicated way of solving this.

Thanks for your help already!

Answer (score 1):

A simple way would be to add the package `authblk` in your preamble and use the command `\affil`. Here is code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{authblk}

\title{The title of this document: XXXXXX}
\author{Author1}
\author{Author2}
\affil{\texttt{(au1, au2)@email-address.com}}
\renewcommand\Authand{\hfil} % default:  \renewcommand\Authand{ and }
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here I use a stack...but it will not process the macro `\and`, so I just use a `\quad and\quad`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\cr}
\title{The title of this document: XXXXXX}
\author{\stackunder{Author1 \quad and\quad Author2}
  {\texttt{\{au1, au2\}@email-adress.com}}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternately, if I use

```
\author{\stackunder{Author1 \qquad Author2}
  {\texttt{\{au1, au2\}@email-adress.com}}}
```

the result is

[image]